# GitHub Pages 404 when trying to host Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: github, polymer, github-pages, polymer-starter-kit

So I'm simply trying to host the polymer-starter-kit on git pages which should be easy enough in theory there's already a simple tutorial for how to do so [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy-to-github-pages.md). The problem is after following all the instructions and navigating to my SKHolmes.github.io I get a 404 from github saying it couldn't load the resources, be that one or many. I can clearly see there is an index.html file in the root directory.

Here is the error
[image]

Here is my repository
[image]

Has anyone had a similar problem? Is there any tricks I'm missing?

Comment: The index.html you're looking at is in the /app folder not at the root.

Comment: I did the same myself about six months ago:  https://jptrainor.github.io

Comment: You could try to make the repo again with no capitalisation. It looks like that github pages need to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [gh-pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) doc? When you want username.gitub.io you need to push to the ´master´ branch, not the 'gh-pages' branch.